# Dynamically generate last 36 month dates

Tags: sql, oracle

How to generate list of dates dynamically for last 36 months in SQL

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Last whole months, or do you want part of months? (Would you expect April dates to be included today?)

Comment: Am using oracle sql and it's rdbms

Comment: I need whole months. No April dates need not be included

Comment: So you want 01-APR-2017 to 31-MAR-2020?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Oracle:

```
select add_months(trunc(sysdate), -36) + level - 1 datum
from dual
connect by level <= trunc(sysdate) - add_months(trunc(sysdate), -36) + 1
order by datum;

DATUM
----------
29.04.2017
30.04.2017
01.05.2017
02.05.2017
03.05.2017
04.05.2017
<snip>
26.04.2020
27.04.2020
28.04.2020
29.04.2020

367 rows selected.
```

Comment: "_I need whole months. No April dates need not be included_"

Comment: What does "36 months" mean, then? Without April 2017 and April 2020 it won't be 36 months but less. I'm not saying that your objection is wrong, @jarlh, but the OP should make it somewhat easier to understand. BTW, didn't see their comment, I was posting my example at the same time (give or take).

Answer (score 0):

```
with t (dt1, dt2) as (
  select trunc(sysdate, 'month') - 1, last_day(trunc(sysdate)) + 1 - interval '36' month from dual
)
select dt2 + level - 1
from t 
connect by       
       dt2 + level - 1 <= dt1 
;
```

`trunc(sysdate, 'month')` gives you the first day of the month at 00 hours.

`last_day(trunc(sysdate))` gives you the last day of the month at 00 hours.